# How to transfer files to mounted disk with sftp?

Tags: permissions, mount, ssh, hard-drive, sftp

So i mounted an external HDD to `/media/data` and now I am trying to use th SFTP protocol to transfer files on the external disk.

Yet anything I try ends up with `permission denied` error:

```
Connected to 192.168.1.14.
sftp> cd /media/data/
sftp> put Test.txt 
Uploading Test.txt to /media/data/Mitja/Test.txt
remote open("/media/data/Test.txt"): Permission denied
```

Any ideas what can I do?

EDIT:
My mount command `/etc/fstab` is:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=e20a628d-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=e20a628d-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
UUID=A2DE-E78C /media/data auto rw,defaults,gid=33,uid=33,umask=0027 0 1
```

And for the purpose of testing I am using "pi" user to sftp.

Comment: @user68186 Edited my OP.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the 'pi' user is `gid=33, uid=33`?  "No permission to access" a location is usually tied specifically to userids and how things're mounted.

Comment: @ThomasWard You are correct, it was not 33. Instead `gid=1000, uid=1000`. And that actually solves the problem. Can you please post an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: @skrat are you using Ubuntu or Raspbian?

Comment: Raspbian Buster Lite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are using wrong UID and GID entries.

As you indicated, your user `pi` is using group ID 1000 and user ID 1000.  Update your mount point as follows in your fstab:

```
UUID=A2DE-E78C /media/data auto rw,defaults,gid=1000,uid=1000,umask=0027 0 1
```